# What is the most pythonic way to call a method with optional parameters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, optional-parameters

Let's say I have a method with a few optional parameters.

`def foo(a, b=1, c=2, d=3)`

How do I go about calling it so that if my variables are None or empty strings the defaults are used?

Conditionals like the following seems like a horrible solution:

```
if b and not c and d:
    foo(myA, b = myB, d = myD)
elif b and not c and not d:
    ...
```

In Java I'd jump for a factory, but it seems like that's what defaults are supposed to avoid in this case.

Comment: In this case I wouldn't use optional parameters, but require them and just check if they have suitable values. But this obviously depends on other details of your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would change `foo` so it replaces empty values with default ones.

```
def foo(a, b=None, c=None, d=None):
    if not b: b = 1
    if not c: c = 2
    if not d: d = 3
```

Note that this will treat all "false-y" values as defaults, meaning not only `None` and `''` but also `0`, `False`, `[]`, etc. Personally I would tighten the interface up and use `None` and only `None` as a default value.

```
def foo(a, b=None, c=None, d=None):
    if b is None: b = 1
    if c is None: c = 2
    if d is None: d = 3
```

Comment: This only checks the truth value of the variables. For example, if `b` were passed in with a value of `0`, then this will still replace it. I only call this out as an error since the OP mentioned checking only for `None` and `''`. If however, OP wants to check for all falsey values, then your solution works just as well (also check out mine for a slightly cleaner implementation using `or`)

Comment: This formulation (`not b`) considers 0 non-existent, which is probably not desirable.

Comment: @delnan According to the OP's example, it should be.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien Assuming OP fully comprehends what that example does. That's not an assumption I'm willing to make blindly.

Comment: I'd make it `foo(a, b=None, c=None, d=None)` to keep the arguments really optional.

Comment: I like the points about tightening the interface. If I find that I'm getting empty strings on the other side due to a lack of value, I'll replace them with `None`.

Answer (score 3):

Though I agree that changing the method is a better idea, here's an alternative that changes the calling part by using a `dict` of arguments, which is filtered and then unpacked:

```
d = {'b': myB, 'd': myD}
foo(myA, **{k: d[k] for k in d if d[k]})
```

Of course `if d[k]` can be replaced by `if d[k] not in {None, ''}` for example, which has a slightly different meaning (as pointed out by others).

Comment: Why not just `**{k: v for k, v in d.items() if v}`?

Comment: @abarnert There's multiple more or less equivalent ways of expressing this. In Python 2.7 `d.items()` returns a `list` rather than an iterator, which in some cases may be bad for performance reasons. It becomes `d.iteritems()` then, which is already less elegant. ;) This one works the same in both versions. [Looking at your reputation I assume I needn't explain that to you, but others might be interested.]

Comment: +1 Thanks for figuring out a way from the caller's point of view. While not ideal, this might be what needs to happen.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien: I think it's still more readable to say `d.iteritems()` if you're in 2.x and have a large dict (for a small one, `d.items()` is fine as-is…) than to explicitly look up `d[k]` twice. (Not that there's a _real_ DRY issue here, much less a performance one, but it will _look_ like one to many readers, and that's often enough reason to avoid it.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch ONLY `None` and `''`:

```
def foo(a, b, c, d):
    blacklist = set([None, ''])
    if b in blacklist:
        b = 1
    if c in blacklist:
        c = 2
    if d in blacklist:
        d = 3
```

If you want to catch all values v such that `bool(v)` is `False`, then:

```
def foo(a, b, c, d):
    b = b or 1
    c = c or 2
    d = d or 3
```

Or you could decorate the function with another function that does the assertions for you (which may or may not be overkill, based on your use case)

Comment: I mostly do it like this. But I still leave them defaulting to None, so you don't have to pass them if you don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

You could call a function that filters out the variables you don't want passed down

```
def arg_filter(**kw):
    return dict((k,v) for k,v in kw.items() if v not in (None, ''))

foo(**arg_filter(a=1,b=None,c=''))
```

Comment: If you want to match the OP's `not c and not d…` logic, just use `if v` as your filter clause. Also, this is Python 2.7, so you can use a dict documentation. So: `return {k: v for k, v in kw.items() if v}`.

Comment: @abarnert - agreed. Any conditions can be used. This example matches the poster's request "if my variables are None or empty strings" by leaving out such things as 0 and False but that can easily be tweaked. The form was chosen on purpose so that it looks much like a regular function call. I find that more esthetically pleasing.

Comment: You seriously find dictionary comprehensions unpleasing compared to calling `dict` on an iterable over tuples?

Answer (score 1):

Not fully tested, but should act as a base:

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps

def force_default(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        ca = inspect.getcallargs(f, *args, **kwargs)
        da = inspect.getargspec(f)
        dv = dict(zip(reversed(da.args), reversed(da.defaults)))
        for k, v in ca.iteritems():
            if v is None or v == '':
                ca[k] = dv[k]
        return f(**ca)
    return func

@force_default
def foo(a, b=1, c=2, d=3):
    print a, b, c, d

foo(6, '', None, 'rabbit!')
# 6 1 2 rabbit!
```